# Add custom metadata in mkdocs

Tags: python, meta-tags, mkdocs

Is there a way to put custom meta tag in the page?
I tryied adding it like documentation says, but only standard tags are parsed to metadata. Custom tags are ignored.

Comment: I found that i can create my custom theme, or modify existing one. Seems hacky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MkDocs only includes support for two metadata keys out-of-the-dox:

- `template`: The template to use with the current page.
- `title`: The "title" to use for the document.

If you would like to use any other metadata keys, then the MkDocs' [documentation](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/writing-your-docs/#meta-data) explains that...

> The key/value pairs are passed by MkDocs to the page template. Therefore, if a theme includes support, the values of any keys can be displayed on the page or used to control the page rendering. See your theme's documentation for information about which keys may be supported, if any.

So, you need to create or modify a theme so that it makes use of the metadata. You may find some third party themes which already do so, or you can create your own theme.